# $.each Jquery working but

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following simple code:

```
<div id="albumTitle">
   <ul>
        <li id="albumTitle1" class="selected"><a  onClick="showAlbum('#albumTitle1','#album1')">Album One</a></li>
        <li id="albumTitle2"><a onClick="showAlbum('#albumTitle1','#album1')">Album Two</a></li>
        <li id="albumTitle3"><a onClick="showAlbum('#albumTitle1','#album1')">Album Three</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

now the albums themselves

```
<div id="albums">

  <div id="album1">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="album2" class="inactive">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="album3" class="inactive">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

so here's what I want...

simply, when I click on an album, the "selected" class goes to that album title and the previously "selected" album class is removed.

Likewise, when the ALBUM is selected, the "inactive" class is 'added' to the previously selected album and 'removed' from the newly selected album.

Here's the code now:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function showAlbum(albTitle, albName) {
        var obj = new Array();

        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            obj.push("album" + x);
        }

        $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
            //alert( key + ": " + value );
            if ($("#" + value).hasClass("inactive")) {
                $("#" + value).removeClass("inactive");
                $("#" + albTitle).removeClass("selected");
            } else {
                $("#" + value).addClass("inactive");
                $("#" + albTitle).addClass("selected");
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: you are passing in the same variables into your `onclick`

Comment: OK, that was my mistake... while copying/writing the code example I forgot to change it... So then if we take into consideration my onClick event is correct... and it still doesn't work, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how's this: http://jsfiddle.net/gqtmh/4/ - it allows you to make the list accessible as it will provide a fallback for if js is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not changed the HTML, it is same as in your original post.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="albumTitle">
   <ul>
        <li id="albumTitle1" class="selected"><a  onClick="showAlbum('#albumTitle1','#album1')">Album One</a></li>
        <li id="albumTitle2"><a onClick="showAlbum('#albumTitle2','#album2')">Album Two</a></li>
        <li id="albumTitle3"><a onClick="showAlbum('#albumTitle3','#album3')">Album Three</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="albums">

  <div id="album1">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="album2" class="inactive">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="album3" class="inactive">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showAlbum(albTitle, albName) {
        $('#albumTitle>ul>li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(albTitle).addClass('selected');
        $('#albums>div').addClass('inactive');
        $(albName).removeClass('inactive');
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected
{
  background-color:blue;    
}
.inactive
{
  background-color:yellow;    
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uxZA7/

Answer (score 0):

You have some logic errors, the first of which is passing `#` on the front of your id, then adding another `#` in your selector. Ideally though, something like this would be a better solution, avoiding inline event handlers:

http://jsfiddle.net/fwmJZ/

```
<div id="albumTitle">
   <ul>
        <li class="album-title" data-album-id="1">Album One</li>
        <li class="album-title" data-album-id="2">Album Two</li>
        <li class="album-title" data-album-id="3">Album Three</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="albums">

  <div class="album" data-album-id="1">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="album" data-album-id="2">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="album" data-album-id="3">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="img/image3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.album-title').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.album-title').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('.album').removeClass('active');
        $('.album[data-album-id='+ $(this).data('album-id') + ']').addClass('active');

    });
});
```